# margin:auto and text-align:center are not working

Tags: html, css, margin, text-align

I'm trying to build a website. For some reason my 'margin: auto' and 'text-align: center' properties are not working. Can someone please check my code out in inspect element and tell me what's wrong?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif, 'Helvetica';
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
#my_cycle_head {
  text-align: center;
}
#main_navbar {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 800px;
}
#main_navbar nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#main_navbar nav {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Cycle - Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="my_cycle_head">My Cycle</h1>
    <navbar id="main_navbar">
      <nav><a href="#">Home</a>
      </nav>
      <nav class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <nav><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a>
      </nav>
      <nav><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </nav>
    </navbar>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<navbar>` is not an HTML element. This would have been picked up if you had [used a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Unrecognised elements are put into the DOM with default styling that includes `display: inline`.

Auto margins and `text-align` have no effect on elements that are `display: inline`.

Use the correct HTML, use `<nav>` (which defaults to `display: block`).

Comment: Is there any possibility to make the text-align have affect?

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your use of `navbar` to `nav` and created a series of `ul` and list items within it to replace all the individual `nav` elements. The `nav` element is meant to be a section of navigation elements, not to mark off each individual navigation point (see more here:  http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/).

I also reordered your CSS and made use of the child selector (https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) to prevent the styles from the main nav rolling down to the dropdown submenu. In this example, all the text is now centered.

```css
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif, 'Helvetica';
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }
    #my_cycle_head {
      text-align: center;
    }
    #main_navbar {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      width: 800px;
    }
    #main_navbar > ul > li {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
    #main_navbar > ul > li > a {
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      padding:0;
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
    .dropdown-content > li {
      display: block;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 id="my_cycle_head">My Cycle</h1>
  <nav id="main_navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please change the navbar with a div

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="my_cycle_head">My Cycle</h1>
    <div id="main_navbar">
      <nav><a href="#">Home</a>
      </nav>
      <nav class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <nav><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a>
      </nav>
      <nav><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt0y3ba1/

Comment: Thanks for it but I just replaced nabber with <nav> and made a <ul> inside it.